# Entity Framework 4.3 Data migration - Single seed method?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have multiple Migrations in my project, each migration adds a number of columns.
After each migration, I want to fill data into the columns, based on the other already existing columns.
I work in a team, and we each have a local database with test data.

Currently there is one single seed method in the configuration class.

With one migration adding columns, adding data in the seed method is fine, but with multiple migrations where every one of them adds columns, it will not work unless i update the seed method to match the most recent migration.

Why didn't they include a virtual or abstract Seed-method for people to override when needed in the DbMigration class? That would seem like a much better way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can seed your data directly in `Up` method in your migration class. Just call:

```
Sql("INSERT INTO ... ");
Sql("UPDATE ... ");
```

`Seed` method in migration configuration is more suitable for initial database seeding when the database is created but it can also be used for upcoming seeds when you need to add or update whole entities - not just initialize columns.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, but i would really really like to be able to use the context, because the new values are a bit complex, and are based on the data already in the table.
Perhaps it is possible to use the ModelDataContext class inside the up. I hope that works, and doesn't kill a small baby seal.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use context in migration.

Comment: Not really the answer i was hoping for, but i guess this is the closest i get :) And i didn't know about being able to execute sql from migration classes. Thanks

Comment: I have had similar issues wanting to seed some data into newly created parts of the database, i havent found any strongly typed way to do this yet, i really want to avoid to execute SQL statements, but it seems, so far, its the only way.